# ASP .NET OnTextChanged event fires twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events, web

I have a textbox field in a `repeater` with `AutoPostback="true"` and an event handler for the `OnTextChanged` event. When I change one of the value of one of the `textboxes` and then click a button that also causes a `postback`, the `OnTextChanged` event fires twice for the same field, and the button event fires once as well.

From creating a simpler sample application and some googling it seems this is not the default behaviour in ASP.NET, which seems to be the button event being swallowed if the `TextChanged` event is fired.

Any tips on how I might have ended up with this apparently nonstandard behaviour?

Comment: Can you please post the markup html?

Comment: Are you changing the `Text` member on postback? E.g. in `Page_Load()`?

Comment: Please, provide us with the actual code, so we don't have to guess the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is very normal since when you are changing a single character in the textbox the ontextchanged event will be fired twice due to deleting a character and then adding another character.